# What "have gone to someone" really mean?

Tags: phrase-usage

I came across this video where the lady that teaches English says, "she has gone to her mother." Supposedly to mean "she is like her mother." It's not that I don't believe her, I'm just double checking. Because, I have never heard that saying. Plus that channel have given wrong information in the past. Anyway, I went ahead and googled the idiom and I couldn't find it, just found another one that is similar to that one. Which is; "be gone to someone"   which means; "to really like/be attracted to someone." I really want to learn English well that's why I'm asking if anyone knows the expression, please share with me.

Link to the video: https://youtu.be/08-5feh91qw

Edit: if you check out the video, jump to min. 8:47 to see her saying the expression.

Comment: If she meant *she's gone on her mother*, then it's fine.

Comment: She's as in she has or she is?

Comment: This may be a little unexpected, but this *'s* is for *is*: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-gone-on-sb.

Comment: Exactly! Damkerng T, that's what I thought and it makes no sense to me. On the lady's context of course.

Comment: Not to be morbid, but if the girl died, and her mother had died beforehand, _She has gone to her mother_ would be a way to say that mother and daughter would be seeing each other again in the afterlife.

Comment: J.R. you're hilarious hahaha.

Comment: @DamkerngT You are familiar with  *she's gone on her mom/mother?* I've never heard it before spoken in any English.

Comment: I can't say that I'm familiar with it. I'm more familiar with *something/someone grows on me*, and I based my guess on that before I tried dictionaries. @AlanCarmack (BTW, it's clearly marked "UK informal" in the Cambridge English Dictionary, so I wouldn't expect American English speakers to be familiar with it either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you are right that she means "she behaves exactly like her mother (calm and doesn't get affected easily)". What she says is not "she's gone to her mother", but "she's gone on her Mom".

How you interpret the sentence is very context-dependent and I don't think many native English speakers would be able to understand what it exactly means without context and say where the expression comes from.

I suspect the expression is only used in India because she uses Indian English.

She said, "She is identical to her Mom" describing the same way she and her mother don't get affected (they are both very calm), I don't think this expression is used that way without a prepositional (adverbial) phrase which adds additional information in terms of how she is identical to her mother. When I hear the sentence, I would assume they look alike as if they were twins.

Comment: Stupid me ): she does really say, "she's gone on her mom." Not "she's gone to her mom/momther." However, I couldn't find an exact idiom that would say; "have/has gone on someone." Only "be gone on someone." So I guess your suspicions about the expression being Indian might be right. Thumbs up, buddy.

Comment: @ManuelHernandez Well, her English doesn't flow very well and it might have slipped from her mouth as she seems more focused on speaking faster (like a native speaker) than getting the meanings across. Her English is not excellent, I would say and I recommend you not watch it.

Comment: @ManuelHernandez Always my pleasure and thanks for accepting this answer. There are many excellent TV shows such as "Good Wife", "Madam Secretary", "House of Cards", etc. with great accents and many useful expressions. Not only are they fun to watch, you can learn a lot of standard and broadly used expressions.

Comment: I will look them up to watch them. Thanks again (:

Comment: Hmm... I just noticed the context. (I hadn't watched the video when I post my comments.) "She's gone on her mom" should mean "She really likes her mom", not "She is really like her mom". Note the different senses between the two "like"s. (BTW, I don't think the English in the video is that bad, even though it's not perfect.)

Comment: @Rathony Sorry if I wasn't clear. I didn't argue with you. I didn't say that you gave any meaning of "be gone on someone" in your answer (because you did not). My message was mainly for the OP. I chose to post it here so you can see my addition information, and may (or may not) include it in your answer as you see fit.

Comment: I doubt your assertion somewhat. Being a non-native speaker, I keep telling myself that anything can happen in a dialect that I'm not familiar with. (For example, a lot of native speakers of English think "How are you going?" doesn't make sense, but it makes perfect sense in a certain dialect.) In this case, I'd like to hear from British English/Indian English speakers, too. I hope some of them will spot this question.

Comment: @Damkerng T. Let me see if I understand, "she's gone on her mom" makes sense to you in the lady's context right? Not so much to me, what I can understand from that point of view is that; "the girl really likes her mom" so "that's why" she's acting like her. Am I right here? But again I'm not a native speaker so Idk. Let me know your understanding of the phrase in her context.

Comment: @ManuelHernandez I thought it would've made sense, but that was before I read Rathony's answer, which prompted me to check how she used it. It's clear that she used it to mean that "She is like her mom" (or in Rathony's words "she behaves exactly like her mother") rather than "She likes her mom". (By the way, even though reading it as "She likes her mom" may make sense, at least for me, it's a bit of a stretch, considering that it seems to suggest "romantic love" rather than "admiration".) Then again, an Indian (or British) English speaker would know more than me how often it's used this way.

Comment: @Damkerng It's obvious that the idiom refers to like as in "sex/romantic attraction" rather than like as in "admiration." Now what I tried to implied when I wrote, "she likes her mom" was that "she admires her mom" that's why she behaves the way she does like if she copies from her mom. Anyway, I think she used it wrongly. I'm not the best person to judge her though.

Comment: @ManuelHernandez But is it always romantic? I don't think it's really romantic in this one: http://www.cartoonsbyjim.com/?sid=35. Then again, I can't be so sure.

Comment: @Damkerng T. Maybe not but check this out: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+gone+on

Comment: @ManuelHernandez Yes, it has such a connotation, as we discussed, but then again, *be attracted to* isn't always used romantically.

Comment: @Damkerng T. I agree with you.